# `\Ddots` intersect the element of matrix and `\Ddots` is short in nicematrix

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I want to type the matrix

[image]

So I try to make this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1&0&0&\Ldots&&0\\
            h_1&2(h_1+h_2)&h_2&&&\Vdots\\
            0&h_2&2(h_2+h_3)&h_3&\Ddots&\\
            \Vdots&\Ddots&\Ddots&\Ddots&\Ddots&0\\
            &&&h_{n-2}&2(h_{n-2}+h_{n-1})&h_{n-1}\\
            0&\Cdots&&0&0&1\\
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Now I get this result:

[image]

I don't want the `\Ddots` intersect the element of matrix and I want `\Ddots` under $2(h_2+h_3)$ is longer (as the first picture). How to make it?

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). By default, `nicematrix` draws the diagonal lines parallel to the first one. It's possible to change the first line drawn. It's also possible to completely deactivate parallelization. However, in your case, the best way is certainly the answer of Simon Dispa (with `\line` in the `\CodeAfter`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a better result by drawing the diagonal dotted lines with the command `\line` in the `\CodeAfter`, including in the case of the second `0` of the last row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1       &0          &0          &\Ldots     &                   &0      \\
            h_1     &2(h_1+h_2) &h_2        &           &                   &\Vdots \\
            0       &h_2        &2(h_2+h_3) &h_3        &\Ddots             &       \\
            \Vdots  &           &           &           &                   &0      \\  % changed <<<<<<<<<
                    &           &           &h_{n-2}    &2(h_{n-2}+h_{n-1}) &h_{n-1}\\
            0       &\Cdots     &           &0          &0                  &1      \\
            \CodeAfter  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
                \line{3-1}{6-4}
                \line{3-2}{5-4}  
                \line{3-3}{5-5}
                \line{3-4}{5-6}
        \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```